# Cascading deletions on a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4.1

I have a [Product]-1-*-[Component].  So when I delete a product, I want EF to delete all its components.  In the designer I select the relationship and set the OnDelete property for End1 to Cascade, whose multiplicity is 0..1 - this generates something like:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Components]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductComponent]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Product_Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Products]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

which to me, means that when a component is deleted, the deletion should cascade and the related product should also be automatically deleted.

This is backwards from what I wanted.  So I edited the property for End2 to Cascade (End1 gets reset to None) but when trying to save the model I get:

```
Error   28  Running transformation: End 'Text' on relationship 
'EF.ProductComponent' cannot have operation specified since its multiplicity 
is '*'. Operations cannot be specified on ends with multiplicity '*'.   C:\Users
\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\X\Website\Models\EF.edmx
```

clearly I don't understand this.  it IS possible to do what I want, no? how?

Comment: In the above you're understanding it backwards.  By applying "on delete" to the foreign key constraint you are saying... if the parent get's deleted, delete me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good link that explains it in detail.  But in short, EF isn't very dependable in handling cascade deletes.  You should set this up on the database end manually because EF probably didn't.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx

And the second part of my answer is.....  A cascade delete works such that if you delete a parent... all the children get deleted as well.  Deleting a child has no effect on the parent whether you have cascade delete on or not.

And yes, the ON DELETE CASCADE should appear on the child table's foreign key constraint.

Another link with good info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx

Comment: I read the link but doesn't the fact that EF creates the FK_ProductComponent constraint with deletion cascading accomplish Golden Rule #1? my problem is that cascading should happen when a product is deleted, not when a component is, but EF doesn't allow me to express that...

Comment: If you've verified that the constraint shown actually exists on the server then as shown it should do what you've described.  Have you tested it and found different.  You stated that you modified the property and got an error but did you test it as it was?

Comment: I figured out what I didn't understand... looked up the docs on adding foreign key constraints.  setting the ON DELETE CASCADE means rows from the altered table will be deleted when the parent table is deleted.  I was thinking the constraint needed to be added to the parent table, not the dependent.  But that's just me being dumb - you did point that out, I guess we only see what we want to see :)

Comment: Totally understand.  Stack overflow is a great place to talk things out.  Hopefully my rambling helped.  Be sure to mark closed if you got your answer.